# Marshal class instance from and to byte array

Tags: c#, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm trying to marshal a class instance from and to byte array using these methods:

Marshal to byte array:

```
        public static byte[] MakeArrayFromCat(Cat cat)
        {
            var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Cat));
            var bytes = new byte[size];
            var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(cat, ptr, false);
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, size);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            return bytes;
        }
```

Marshal to class instance:

```
 public static Cat MakeCatFromArray(byte[] b)
        {
            var size = b.Length;
            var bytes = new byte[size];
            var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, size);
            var cat = (Cat)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(Cat));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            return cat;
        }
```

Here's my class:

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public class Cat
    {
        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public Cat (string name, int age, int weight)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
            Weight = weight;
        }
    }
```

So when I run the presented methods the program throws MissingMethodException meaning that there's no constructor that takes no arguements. I get it on this line (in MakeCatFromArray method):

`var cat = (Cat)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(Cat));`

I've tried to add a default constructor, but what I get from it doesn't live up to what I expect: It gives me an instance with all its properties empty, although I marshalled an instance with non-default values. Thus I've got two questions:

1.How do I do marshalling properly in this case?
2.Is there any better way of converting an instance of a class into byte array **without** marking it as `[Serializable]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this:

```
Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, size);
```

You are trying to create Cat from empty bytes array.

There should be `b` instead of `bytes`:

```
Marshal.Copy(b, 0, ptr, size);
```